# NSIS installer (on OS X) gives 'Invalid command: TargetMinimalOS'

Tags: macos, nsis

I built NSIS 2.46 on my OS X computer according to the instructions provided at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html#G.3. The build worked fine and it correctly creates my installer.

My installer is fully working, but I tried to add the command:

TargetMinimalOS 5.0

This isn't essential to my task; as I understand it, all it does it let the installer run in Unicode, which isn't necessary. Just seemed like something that would be sensible to add, as I don't support older Windows versions anyway. I put it right after the command 'SetCompressor lzma', which works fine. However, makensis reports:

[...]
SetCompressor: lzma
Invalid command: TargetMinimalOS

and then aborts.

To check I had it right, I copy-pasted it directly from the documentation (can't add the hyperlink - Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.2.9 at same site as above) but it still gives that error. The error is the same one as if I make up a stupid command name like 'FrogXyzzy'.

I will solve this problem by not using the command! However, does anyone know why it did not work? Is this a problem to do with the way I built nsis? (I prefer not to use DarwinPorts or Fink, but maybe they would have built it differently...) Or am I doing something stupid with the command name that I haven't spotted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The online docs are generated from SVN and are ahead of the stable build (2.46 currently)

If you need unicode today, you have to use the scratchpaper.com fork or compile from SVN yourself (The fork will be merged back in and the next official version will be unicode)

Answer (score 1):

Under [the section on Unicode installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter1.html#1.4), it starts "Starting with MakeNSIS v2.50....".  This implies that the functionality isn't available in 2.46.  Looks like they got a bit premature with the documentation.

Far as i can tell, prior to 2.50, there's [a separate Unicode version of NSIS](http://www.scratchpaper.com/).  No guarantees about whether it'll even compile on OSX, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I think TargetMinimalOS might change the major and minor subsystem versions in the PE format of the installer executable so that it runs on older operating systems. Since NSIS is supposed to work on Windows 95, one of the things I did was try to run my installer in Windows 95. When I did it gave an error saying that the installer required an upgraded version of Windows to run. I was able to get it to run on Windows 95 when I changed the subsystem version of the installer executable to 4.0. There is a utility called EditVersion.exe from [LegacyExtender](http://www.legacyextender.com/) that allowed me to do it.